# cannot run pyspark in another pycharm project

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm, environment-variables

I managed to set up Spark locally on Mac v10.15.7 and on one of my Pycharm project (let's call it project A). However I wasn't able to start Spark in another Pycharm project (Project B) that I just set up by using the same interpreter as Project A.

In Project B environment I seem to be able to call the spark session. When I go to `http://localhost:4040/`  a spark session was set up. However when I start executing commands I received messages like

```
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

When I call `pyspark` in Project B pycharm terminal I got the error message below. Although I do manage to call spark by running the same command from Project A pycharm terminal and Macbook `Terminal` .

```
macbook:projectB byc$ pyspark
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/Users/byc/PycharmProjects', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin']

Did you install PySpark via a package manager such as pip or Conda? If so,
PySpark was not found in your Python environment. It is possible your
Python environment does not properly bind with your package manager.

Please check your default 'python' and if you set PYSPARK_PYTHON and/or
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON environment variables, and see if you can import
PySpark, for example, 'python -c 'import pyspark'.

If you cannot import, you can install by using the Python executable directly,
for example, 'python -m pip install pyspark [--user]'. Otherwise, you can also
explicitly set the Python executable, that has PySpark installed, to
PYSPARK_PYTHON or PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON environment variables, for example,
'PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 pyspark'.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pyspark: line 24: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pyspark: line 68: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pyspark: line 68: exec: /bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Looking through various posts here I added my environment variables

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Download/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Download/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec
PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

Shut down Project B Pycharm again, reopen and run the command again. Still no luck.
I'm sure I missed a few obvious parts here but just couldn't figure out what they are! Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try `SPARK_HOME=/Download/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7`.

No need to set `PYTHONPATH`.

If setting `SPARK_HOME` doesn't work, you might need to specify a correct path to the python executable in `PYSPARK_PYTHON`. The path you provided doesn't look right. Maybe it'll be something like `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @mck. I re-set the environment variables as follows `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.7;PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Download/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python;SPARK_HOME=/Download/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7 `.

Comment: In addition to these variables I've also added two content roots --- still no luck...! `/Users/byc/Downloads/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip`; `/Users/byc/Downloads/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pyspark with pip installer.

```
pip install pyspark==2.4.7
```

If you are using it locally, I would also suggest that you setup the following:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.6
```